# Async/Await function not waiting for promise to end

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
let myObject = ( () => {

  let run = async() => {
    foo = new genericFunction();
    status = await foo.myFunction();
  }

})();
```

#### Another FIle.js

```
let genericFunction = function() {


  this.getData = async () => {
    $.getJSON("path/to/file.json", function (data) {
      console.log("Apple", data.name);
      return data.name;
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log("Loading Error :: ", error);
    )};

  }


  this.myFunction = async () => {
    let data = this.getData();
    console.log('DATAA:::', data); //This should be the first output
  }

}
```

The problem is: 
`status` is always `= undefined` because somehow it returns before `getJSON` executes and I don't know why.

Comment: You need to add `async` on your function declaration as well.

Comment: `this.getData` is missing await, async is not enough

Answer (score 1):

**Another FIle.js** should be like:

```
let genericFunction = function() {


  this.getData = async () => {
    var result = await $.getJSON("path/to/file.json", function (data) {
      console.log("Apple", data.name);
      return data.name;
    }).catch(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log("Loading Error :: ", error);
    )};

    return result;
  }


  this.myFunction = async () => {
    let data = this.getData();
    console.log('DATAA:::', data); //This should be the first output
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example using your code but with a couple of changes:

1) Uses a `class`

2) You're not returning anything from `myFunction` so there's no reason to assign something to `status` - just call the function.

3) `getData` doesn't need an async keyword, and you need to return the promise (in this example I mocked up a AJAX call that returns data after a second) from the function for it to work.

4) You do need to `await` for the promise to return in `myFunction`. You have `async` there, you just need to add the `await` keyword too.

```js
class GenericFunction {

  getData() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('Hello World'), 2000);
    });
  }

  async myFunction() {
    let data = await this.getData();
    console.log('DATAA:::', data);
  }

}

(async () => {
  const foo = new GenericFunction();
  foo.myFunction();
})();
```